Burninate the cryptology tag
There was a question about the difference between cryptography and cryptology. Even if there is a positive answer: there is a difference then I think the difference is too small; almost nobody in the community will understand the difference. Tagging questions with cryptology will therefore only spread confusion.
The only tag where it makes sense is the singular question about the difference. Although the question in itself is fine, I propose to burninate the cryptology tag; having a single-use tag is - well - useless.

The burninate-request tag was copied from meta.SO by the way. It's not single use :P

Since you removed the tag, it'll get deleted automatically. This kind of meta question is mainly used if a tag is used often buy should still be removed.

@CodesInChaos Ah, thanks, I didn't know that. Great, problem solved, I'd even accept that as an answer :)

Also this kind of post is needed if a tag should be black-listed (that is banned from re-creation which requires a SE staff member).

@SEJPM Cool, I don't think that's needed until it is used multiple times while it shouldn't, right? So no action for this particular tag I presume?

yep, that's it.

Converting the relevant comments into an answer:

Since you removed the tag, it'll get deleted automatically. This kind of meta question is mainly used if a tag is used often but should still be removed. – CodesInChaos♦

Also this kind of post is needed if a tag should be black-listed (that is banned from re-creation which requires a SE staff member). – SEJPM♦

And in case you're wondering why it took 3 mods to compile this answer — think "teamwork". ;)
